# dcm api Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on null

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-apis-explorer

im trying to execute this code

```
$startDate = new DateTime("2018-01-15", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$endDate = new DateTime("2018-01-16", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

$AdvertiserId="4103310";
$DefaultLandingPageId="8925159";
$Name="2018|Q1|TESTapp|FRA";

$campaign = new Google_Service_Dfareporting_Campaign();
$campaign->setAdvertiserId($AdvertiserId);
$campaign->setDefaultLandingPageId($DefaultLandingPageId);
$campaign->setName($Name);
$campaign->setStartDate($startDate->format('Y-m-d'));
$campaign->setEndDate($endDate->format('Y-m-d'));

$userProfileId = '3177467';

//call api dcm

$result = $service->campaigns->insert(
$values[$userProfileId], 
$campaign
);

$startDate = new DateTime("2018-01-15", new    DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$endDate = new DateTime("2018-01-16", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$AdvertiserId="4103310";
$DefaultLandingPageId="8925159";
$Name="2018|Q1|TESTapp|FRA";
$campaign = new Google_Service_Dfareporting_Campaign();
$campaign->setAdvertiserId($AdvertiserId);
$campaign->setDefaultLandingPageId($DefaultLandingPageId);
$campaign->setName($Name);
$campaign->setStartDate($startDate->format('Y-m-d'));
$campaign->setEndDate($endDate->format('Y-m-d'));
$userProfileId = '3177467';
//call api dcm
$result = $service->campaigns->insert(
$values[$userProfileId], 
$campaign
);
```

when i launch this code in wamp i have the error message below

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on null in
>   C:\wamp64\www\scripts\apptest3.php on line 123"

How can i debug this error?

Comment: Know nothing about dcm api but your source code does not show where did you find `$service` variable.

Comment: formatted error code and removed extra comments, your error code tells you exactly where to look for errors